# Rails Tutorial: use of instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am in section [8.4.3 - Forgetting Users](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-forgetting_users) of the Rails Tutorial.

```
# app/helpers/session_helper.rb
module SessionsHelper
...
  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Logs out the current user
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
...
end
```

In the `current_user` method we assign a user to the `@current_user` instance variable. I don't understand why we don't use that same instance variable in the `log_out` method (in that method `current_user` is not prepended with an @ symbol). Where does `current_user` come from then since it isn't passed in as an argument to that method?

Comment: current_user is a helper method https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: `forget(current_user)` it is calling helper `current_user`. Ruby methods default return last executed line. So `current_user` helper will return `@current_user` object if user logged_id.

Comment: Another important to note here is that `@current_user` is not set until you call the `current_user` method. So in the scope of the `log_out` method, you have to assume `@current_user` doesn't exist until you run the method that creates it, which is `current_user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't make difference between a method invocation and a local variable. That is the reason why `current_user` might look like both.
In your case it's the defined method.

You can actually use both `@current_user` and `current_user` as the returned value of that method should be equal to `@current_user`.

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is the method defined at the snippet you posted of the page.

`@current_user` is the instance variable set BY `current_user`

So when you look at the code:

```
# Defines a method called log_out
def log_out
  # Calls the 'forget' method on the result of the 'current_user' method,
  #   which sets @current_user
  forget(current_user)
  # Deletes the session variable named 'user_id'
  session.delete(:user_id)
  # Resets @current_user to nil, because there should no longer be one
  @current_user = nil
end
```

If I wanted to look at it differently, I could say:

```
def log_out
  # Sets @current_user
  current_user
  # Calls the forget method on the variable @current_user
  forget(@current_user)
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
end
```

But I could NOT change the last line to `current_user = nil` instead of `@current_user = nil`, because then I am assigning the nil value to the name of a method instead of to the instance variable.

Part of the reason method calls and variables look so similar in Ruby is that everything is handled as an object, so methods are *essentially* just a variable whose value is a block of code (there are technical differences to what we call a "block" and a method, but conceptually this is a decent analogy). When we define a method, we save it into what is, more or less, a variable. Thus if we think about the method "current_user", we may instead think of it as a variable "current_user" whose value is `forget(current_user); session.delete(:user_id); @current_user=nil`.

This is an oversimplification, of course, but it is worth keeping in mind as you go forward with your learning.